# When does java TreeMap makes sorting?

Tags: java, collections

Could anyone say when TeeMap makes sorting - on adding entries via put method or, for example, before we iterate the map? I tried to find in javadoc but with no luck.

Comment: The treemap will always be sorted so it _has_ to happen when adding/removing elements. The Javadoc for the class itself already hints at that: "This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations" - the cost for those methods stems from the need to look up an element (either the one you look for or the one to insert before or after).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find out?  From developer's perspective this collection is **always** ordered.

Answer (score 2):

It's done during the altering operations.

For exemple, here is the jdk8 implementation of the method `put` :

```java
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        Entry<K,V> t = root;
        if (t == null) {
            compare(key, key); // type (and possibly null) check

            root = new Entry<>(key, value, null);
            size = 1;
            modCount++;
            return null;
        }
        int cmp;
        Entry<K,V> parent;
        // split comparator and comparable paths
        Comparator<? super K> cpr = comparator;
        if (cpr != null) {
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = cpr.compare(key, t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
        else {
            if (key == null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                Comparable<? super K> k = (Comparable<? super K>) key;
            do {
                parent = t;
                cmp = k.compareTo(t.key);
                if (cmp < 0)
                    t = t.left;
                else if (cmp > 0)
                    t = t.right;
                else
                    return t.setValue(value);
            } while (t != null);
        }
        Entry<K,V> e = new Entry<>(key, value, parent);
        if (cmp < 0)
            parent.left = e;
        else
            parent.right = e;
        fixAfterInsertion(e);
        size++;
        modCount++;
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What about `remove()`?

Comment: It will be the same for *all* altering operations (put/putAll/remove/etc...)

Comment: You can find here the whole implementation of `TreeMap` : http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/TreeMap.java